# Does session_start in PHP prevent session expiration?

Tags: php, session

I'm somewhat bewildered about using `session_start` in `PHP`. Should I use it in my scripts both when user initially creates session and when resumes it on consequent queries - or only when creating?

Currently I do not call it when session already exists but I have found that session sometimes expires unexpectedly fast:

For example, from public log of my site I see:

```
srinivasvarma678 09:14:34 27-Jun-14
    I've just logged in...

...

srinivasvarma678 08:59:38 27-Jun-14
    I'm proud to tell I've just solved Vowel Count!
```

I.e. user's last interaction with site was at 8:59 and then in 15 minutes he needs to log in again (though `session.gc_maxlifetime=1440`)

Could this behavior be explained by the fact I am not calling `session_start` every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

As stated [here](https://www.php.net/session_start) in the PHP docs:

```
session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a 
session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.
```

So if you want to `continue` the session, you should always use `session_start()` on every page...

Comment: Thanks for explanations and link, I'll try to remove this clumsy prevention of calling the function and see if it helps!

Comment: @RodionGorkovenko, no problem. Hope it will fix your problem. If you have an `config` file that you include everywhere in the top of the page, you can `sessions_start()` there. That way you only have to include the config file to start the session.... But i don't know how your app is structured...

Comment: No such problem - though I use some clumsy makeshift framework, it has a single method where `session_start` is called so it appeared not that hard. Really it already looks like situation improved, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

session_start() allows you to use sessions in your script.

You should use it both when creating new sessions or reusing existent one.

It also updates the session, to it won't be garbage collected and removed.